# How to select a date with a set cell color in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a macro in excel VBA, that searches the Range (B1:B30) of the value of the ActiveCell in Column “B” by a loop. Along with the search of Column, I also want to check if the date’s cell is colored with a particular color. If the date's cell equals the set color "Good", then I want it to change the color of the cell in Column H of the same row as selected to red.

When I run the code, I get an error message of “Run-time error ‘424’: Object required.” When I go to debug the problem, it highlights the .Find function I have and points to the last line of the search which is “SearchFormat:=False).Activate” What should I do to fix this problem? 
Any improvement with my overall code will be very much appreciated.

```
Sub Find()

Dim FirstAddress As String
Dim MySearch As Variant
Dim Rng As Range
Dim I As Long


MySearch = Array(ActiveCell)

    With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B30")

        For I = LBound(MySearch) To UBound(MySearch)

            Set Rng = .Find(What:=MySearch(I), _
                        After:=ActiveCell, _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        SearchFormat:=False).Activate


         If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                FirstAddress = Rng.Address
                Do
                    If ActiveCell.Style.Name = "Good" Then
                        Rng("H" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
                        Rng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexRed

                    End If

                    Set Rng = .FindNext(Rng)
                Loop While Not Rng Is Nothing And Rng.Address <> FirstAddress
            End If
        Next I
    End With

End Sub
```

#### Showing the Debug mode of the run-time error.

[image: Showing the Debug mode of the run-time error.]

#### Screenshot of the Spreadsheet for reference

[image: Screenshot of the Spreadsheet for reference]

Comment: ActiveCell is the position of current selected cell.So MySearch will always have any array of single value.Which gives you the LBound(MySearch) as 0 always.I guess that is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code Review:**

You have several problems here.

`MySearch = Array(ActiveCell)` will always be a single value.  So why bother looping through it

You cannot set a range to equal range.activate.  Searching `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B30")` implies that you are searching a worksheet other that the ActiveSheet.  If this is the case than `.Find(After:=Activecell)` suggests that you are looking for a value after the ActiveCell of another worksheet.

Set Rng = .Find(What:=MySearch(I), _
                        After:=ActiveCell, _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        SearchFormat:=False).Activate

`Rng("H" & ActiveCell.Row)` Rng is a Range object.  It doesn't work like Range.  You cannot pass it a cell address.  You can do this `Rng(1,"H")` which is really shorthand for `Rng.cells(1,"H")` bit that is misleading because `Rng` is in column 2 `Rng(1,"H")` will reference the value in column I.

```
Sub Find()
    Dim FirstAddress As String
    Dim MySearch As Variant
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim I As Long


    MySearch = ActiveCell 'This is the ActiveCell of the ActiveSheet not necessarily Sheets("Sheet1")

    With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B30")

        Set Rng = .Find(What:=MySearch, _
                        After:=.Range("B1"), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        SearchFormat:=False)


        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            FirstAddress = Rng.Address
            Do
                If Rng.Style.Name = "Good" Then

                    .Range("H" & Rng.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexRed

                End If

                Set Rng = .FindNext(Rng)
            Loop While Not Rng Is Nothing And Rng.Address <> FirstAddress
        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Here is the actual answer to your question:

```
Sub FindMatchingValue()
    Const AllUsedCellsColumnB = False
    Dim rFound As Range, SearchRange As Range

    If AllUsedCellsColumnB Then
        Set SearchRange = Range("B1", Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp))
    Else
        Set SearchRange = Range("B1:B30")
    End If

    If Intersect(SearchRange, ActiveCell) Is Nothing Then
        SearchRange.Select
        MsgBox "You must select a cell in the highlighted area before continuing", vbInformation, "Action Cancelled"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set rFound = SearchRange.Find(What:=ActiveCell.Value, _
                                  After:=ActiveCell, _
                                  LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                  LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                  SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                  SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                  SearchFormat:=False)



    If Not rFound Is Nothing Then

        Do

            If rFound.Style.Name = "Good" Then

                Range("H" & rFound.Row).Interior.Color = vbRed

            End If

            Set rFound = SearchRange.FindNext(rFound)

        Loop While Not rFound Is Nothing And rFound.Address <> ActiveCell.Address
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your insight, I've tried your code and now I get a different error. The error that is showing is "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch." and the VBA code that is selected in the debug window is the same what I described above.

Comment: I updated my answer to include an actual answer to your question.  If the ActiveCell is not in the search range then my answer will have to be adjusted.

Comment: Thank you for your updated answer. This is working for how I was hoping for. Thank you very much!

Comment: I glad that I was able to help.  Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You can't put `Activate` at the end of the `find`the way you are trying to do.

Try this as you find statement.

```
Set Rng = .Find(What:=MySearch(I), _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False, _
                        SearchFormat:=False)
    Rng.Activate
```

Then if you want to `Activate` the range, do that. But, it is best to stay away from `Select`, `Activate` etc in VBA code. I strongly suggest not using that last line of code and adjust you code to not rely on `Select` and `Activate`.

Comment: Thank you for your insight as well, I have replaced this section of my code with yours and I seem to be getting another error message. The message that comes up is "Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument. The section of my code that is highlighted in debug mode is shown in bold: 'If ActiveCell.Style.Name = "Good" Then
                        **Rng("H" & ActiveCell.Row).Select**
                        Rng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexRed
'

Answer (score 0):

you may want to consider an Autofilter approach so as to loop only through relevant cells, as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Find()
    Dim cell As Range

    With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B30")
        .Rows(1).Insert '<--| insert a dummy header cell to exploit Autofilter. it'll be removed by the end
        With .Offset(-1).Resize(.Rows.Count + 1) '<--| consider the range expanded up to the dummy header cell
            .Rows(1) = "header" '<--| give the dummy header cell a dummy name
            .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=ActiveCell '<--| filter range on the wanted criteria
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then '<--| if any cell other than "header" one has been filtered...
                For Each cell In .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)  '<--| ... loop through filtered cells only
                    If cell.Style.Name = "Good" Then cell.Offset(, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 '<--| ... and color only properly styled cells
                Next cell
            End If
            .AutoFilter '<--| .. show all rows back...
        End With
        .Offset(-1).Resize(1).Delete '<--|delete dummy header cell
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I appreciate what you have provided me. I have tried your code, and the dummy header inserts and removes, but I'm not seeing anything else done. The active cell doesn't change, the values in the H column doesn't change color. Now looking at your code again, I am not seeing a action for that to happen. If that is the case, my apologies.

Comment: the activecell must not change, its value is simply taken as the filtering criteria (`.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=ActiveCell`). The filtered range is "B1:B30" of the worksheet "Sheet1" and for its every cell whose style is named "Good" the corresponding cell in column "H" is backcolored in red. I tested it, so you just check all those names and change to your actual ones.

Comment: @Munstr : did you get through it?

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. I have not been able to work on this due to heavy family problems. I do understand what you are saying though. Thank you for your help.

Comment: sorry for that. hoping you can get back as soon as possible to these matter, and I'll help you.

Comment: I understand what your block of code does. It is a nice feature. Though it's not best suited for my needs. Thank you for your help and time with my questions. And thank you for checking in a few days ago, I didn't expect that.

Comment: You are welcome. Consider Autofilter in your coding habits since it's a very powerful and fast feature.